# Expanding a list columns to multiple columns using pandas assign

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 'b,c,d'},{'a': 'c,d'},{'a': 'd,c,d'}])
test

    a 
0   b,c,d 
1   c,d 
2   d,c,d
```

I want to expand the column 'a' into three different new columns.

I know how to do it using this command:

```
test[['Column1', 'Column2','Column3']] = test['a'].str.split(',', expand=True)

    a   Column1     Column2     Column3
0   b,c,d   b   c   d
1   c,d     c   d   None
2   d,c,d   d   c   d
```

However, I'm interested in a solution using pandas.assign function.

I tried this one, but I only recovered the first column.

```
test = test.assign(a = lambda x: x['a'].str.split(',', expand = True))

test

    a
0   b
1   c
2   d
```

How would I do that?

Comment: You might be better off with join here? `test.join(test['a'].str.split(',', expand = True))`

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to using `assign`

```
test.assign(**{str(k): v for k,v in (test['a'].str.split(',', expand=True).to_dict('l')).items()})
Out[898]: 
       a  0  1     2
0  b,c,d  b  c     d
1    c,d  c  d  None
2  d,c,d  d  c     d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use assign, you can do this:

```
    df.assign(**dict(zip(['Column1','Column2','Column3'],
                         df.a.str.split(',',expand=True).values.T)))
Out[19]: 
       a Column1 Column2 Column3
0  b,c,d       b       c       d
1    c,d       c       d    None
2  d,c,d       d       c       d
```